# Not understanding C++ type mismatch: const Foo* to Foo* const&

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, constants

Having this set of objects and statements:

```
QSet<Foo*> set;
iterator QSet::insert(const T & value)    //type of the function I want to call
const Foo * get() const                   //type of the function I use to get the argument

set.insert(get());                        //the line showing up as error
```

I get the error "no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const Foo*' to 'Foo* const&". I guess I have trouble reading these types because I have no idea what I should do to make this work.

From what I've read, the const keyword applies to the type to its left with the exception of a top-level const which can be written to the left of the type it applies to. My guess would be that I have to convert get() to a reference but I'm unsure how to do that.

Comment: This isn't "top-level `const`". `get()` returns a pointer to "`const Foo`", not a `const` pointer.

Comment: So my understanding that a `const` at the beginning applies to everything to its right was wrong? What exactly does such a `const` apply to then?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There seem to be a couple of misunderstandings here (both by the questioner and by some answers).

**First**, you said "My guess would be that I have to convert `get()` to a reference but I'm unsure how to do that". Let's try clearing this up:

1) "I have to convert `get()` to a reference" -- Actually, you don't!

`iterator QSet::insert(const T & value)` does indeed take a reference. But it's a reference to type `T`. So the question is, "what is type `T`"?

In this case, `T=Foo *`. So `insert`, in this instance of the template, is actually:

`iterator QSet::insert(Foo * const & value)` -- read it from right to left: `insert` takes a reference to a constant pointer to a `Foo`.

2) "I'm unsure how to do that [convert a pointer to a reference]" -- while you don't have to do it here, in general you do this by de-referencing the result of get. For example: `*(get())`.

**Second**, the compiler error. The error arises because there is a conflict:

a) `get()` returns a `const Foo *`

b) but `set` stores a `Foo*` -- NOT a `const Foo *`, so `insert` only accepts a changeable `Foo`

So you can't store a constant pointer inside your `QSet<Foo*>`. This makes sense because you can use `set` to access and change the `Foo`s inside it, which you promise not to do with a `const Foo`.

This reference should be helpful:

https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness

You may also think whether you can just use a `QSet<Foo>` instead of a `QSet<Foo*>`. In the former case, things will probably behave how you expect.

Comment: Looking at https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#const-ref-alt, is it true that `const X*` is equivalent to `X const*` for arbitrarily complex type constructs `X`?

Comment: It is when `X` is a type -- it's not if `X` is more complicated.. In fact, that's why I had to do exactly that swap before substituting in for `T`. Writing it `X const*` makes it easier to read from right to left ("a pointer to a constant `X`). But writing it `const X*` makes it more evident in the source code that the type is "a constant `X`". So usually you see it `const X*` in code.

Comment: For templates it might be confusing, so... Whoever wrote `QSet` could have coded `insert(const T & value) ` or `insert(T const & value)` and they would have been the same. But that's because the compiler knows what to do. If **you** want to substitute in for `T` on paper or in your head, you **must** think of it as `insert(T const & value)` before doing the substitution.

Comment: So `const (int *) * pcp` would be a pointer to a const pointer to an int? Or is this an invalid case?

Comment: I don't think you can use the parentheses like that. g++ gives me a compiler error. Without the parentheses, `const int ** pcp` would be a changeable pointer to a changeable pointer to a constant `int`, while `int * const * pcp` would be a changeable pointer to a constant pointer to a changeable `int`.

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to take a `const Foo *` and insert it into a `QSet<Foo *>`, but the compiler won't automatically convert a `const Foo *` to a plain `Foo *` in order to do so.

Comment: @Jefffrey: Because the `QSet<Foo *>` contains non-const pointers. You can't change a pointer-to-const into a pointer-to-nonconst implicitly.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem by changing the type of the set as follows.

```
QSet<Foo const*> set;
```

With this change, compilation succeeds.

Answer (score 3):

You're violating the const-ness of the pointer returned from your `get()` function.  `get()` returns a pointer to a const object of type `Foo`, but then you try to insert it into a vector of non-const `Foo` pointers.  You need to `const_cast` the return value from `get()` or change the return type of `get()` from `const Foo*` to just `Foo*`.

Comment: These would have been the other two alternatives.